# iOS - how to handle string concatenation when a value can be nil?

Tags: ios, ios5, string-concatenation

I am doing something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *var1 = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"obj1"];
NSString *var2 = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"obj2"]; 

EmailUtil *email_obj = [[EmailUtil alloc] initWithSubject:@"Some subject" body:[[[@"This is var1: " stringByAppendingString: var1] stringByAppendingString:@" and var2: "] stringByAppendingString: var2]]; 

[email_obj send];
```

Where EmailUtil is just my own utility class which sends the email. This code works fine when the strings var1 and var2 are not nil; however, if they are nil the program will crash. What would be an elegant solution or good practice to follow to ensure the email is sent without a problem, regardless of what the values are?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using `NSMutableString` (or `+stringWithFormat:`) to build up strings. It will lead to much cleaner code than many nested `stringByAppendingString:` calls.

Comment: @Mike Weller yeah I dont like the stringByAppendString thing but up to now if felt like the most reasonable solution.  Would you mind posting a snippet for how to work with the mutable string? I am just not too familiar with it.

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is var1: %@, this is var2: %@", var1, var2]` is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your EmailUtil line, just add:

```
if(var1==nil) var1 = @"";
if(var2==nil) var2 = @"";
```

That should solve the crash at least.

Another and probably better way to do it would be to use NSString's stringWithFormat.
Instead of:

```
[[[@"This is var1: " stringByAppendingString: var1] stringByAppendingString:@" and var2: "] stringByAppendingString: var2]
```

Do:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is var1: %@ and var2: %@", var1,var2];
```

I believe it will say (null) for the nil parameters (didn't test this). This is probably cleaner than what I had, and your original code too.

Reference: [String Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943)

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to create a `NSUserDefaults` category with a method that returned a guaranteed string, substituting @"" for nil or perhaps a default value that you provide.  It might be overkill if your only concern (ever!) is two variables but it might also be handy for re-use.